How may I find the distribution of a transformation of multivariate random variables?
Forgive me if this question has already been asked on here, but I could only find posts if the multivariate random variables were multivariate Gaussian.
Suppose we have two multivariate random variables $\mathbf{x}\sim P(\boldsymbol{\theta}_x)$ and $\mathbf{y}\sim P(\boldsymbol{\theta}_y)$ of dimension $d$, which belong to the same family of distributions $P$ with different parameters. Thus, they are not identically distributed, but (for ease) let's assume they are in fact independent. Further, suppose I'm interested in finding the distribution of $\mathbf{z}=g(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$. To have a concrete and nontrivial example, let's consider the Euclidean distance $\mathbf{z}=||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||$.
Traditional methods to find the distribution for a transformation of random variables is to propose two transformations $\mathbf{z}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=g(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$, solve for $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ in terms of $\mathbf{z}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, and find the joint distribution of $\mathbf{z}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$. Am I correct in my approach for finding such a joint distribution:
$$f_{\mathbf{Z},\boldsymbol{\alpha}}(\mathbf{z},\boldsymbol{\alpha})=f_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}(h_1(\mathbf{z},\boldsymbol{\alpha}),h_2(\mathbf{z},\boldsymbol{\alpha}))|J|,$$
which was adapted from Theorem 4.3.2 in Casella & Berger's book, where the $h_{1/2}(\cdot,\cdot)$ functions are $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, respectively, expressed in terms of $\mathbf{z}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, and $|J|$ is the determinant of some Jacobian matrix? If so, how may I go about solving for $|J|$? I'm not sure what this would look like in a multivariate setting.
Thank you for your time.
Update:
As whuber recommended, we concatenate the $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ into a vector $\mathbf{w}$ of dimension $2d$. Then, we can find the distribution of $z$ by first considering the joint distribution
$$f_{z,\boldsymbol{\alpha}}(z,\boldsymbol{\alpha})=f_{w_1,...,w_{2d}}(h_1(z,\boldsymbol{\alpha}),...,h_{2d}(z,\boldsymbol{\alpha})|J|,$$
where $|J|$ is the Jacobian of the transformation. Now, the current challenge lies in specifying the $\alpha_i$ to ensure we can obtain one-to-one transformations between $\mathbf{w}$ and $(z,\boldsymbol{\alpha})$.

A quick search finds several dozen closely related posts: have you considered researching the answers that are already available here on CV? To apply them, simply recognize that $\mathbf w  = (\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$ is a (vector-valued) random variable and $g:\mathbb R^{2d}\to\mathbb R^{2d}$ transforms $\mathbf w$ to another vector-valued random variable.  The incidentals about being from the same family and even being independent are irrelevant: the theory remains the same.

BTW, concerning "only find:" my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154298/919 shows up in that search and concerns (as an example) a transformation involving Gamma and Dirichlet variables, none of which are Gaussian.

@whuber I did not greatly consider concatenating the $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ into $\mathbf{w}$ because the transformations of $\mathbf{w}$ would seem complicated by indexing. For example, with Euclidean distance, if $\mathbf{w}=(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$, then $\mathbf{z}=g(\mathbf{w})=\sqrt{(w_1-w_{d+1})^2+...+(w_d-w_{2d})^2}$, which implies $g:\mathbb{R}^{2d}\to\mathbb{R}^+$. Initially, I thought this would complicate the Jacobian for $\mathbf{w}$. Also, the specification of another function $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=h(\mathbf{w})$ seems hard to specify, though that may be another problem.

I did enjoy reading your linked response that covers differential algebra. I think that is a better way to solve for the Jacobian than what I was taught in school. I'll try using that!

In practice, the subtlest part of all this is keeping track of many-to-one transformations as in your example, because that multiplicity is not automatically handled by the formalism of Jacobians or differential algebra.  This is an issue even for some univariate functions, as illustrated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/138922/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/418071/919.

@whuber Using your concatenation idea, am I correct in assuming that the joint distribution between $z=g(\mathbf{w})=||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||$ and $\alpha=h(\mathbf{w})=∠(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$, where $\alpha$ is the angular distance between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, is given by $$f_{z,\alpha}(z,\alpha)=f_{w_1,...,w_{2d}}(h_1(z,\alpha),...,h_{2d}(z,\alpha))|J|$$ with a rectangular Jacobian matrix with $i$th row $(\partial w_i/\partial z, \partial w_i/\partial \alpha)$. This seems wrong because $w$ has dimension $2d$, but $z$ and $\alpha$ consist of just 2 dimensions.

I assume that the specification for $\alpha$ is faulty. Perhaps I need it to have dimension $2d-1$ such that we have $2d$ knowns and $2d$ unknowns. I suppose that's sort of what you did in the gamma/Dirichlet problem. You had $Z$ be just one-dimension because you were one dimension short in defining the transformations $Y_i$. You choice in $Z$ seems pretty clear in hindsight, but I think specifying an appropriate $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ with dimension $2d-1$ will be rather difficult.

@whuber If we assume $z=g(\mathbf{w})$ is of dimension 1 and $\mathbf{w}$ is of dimension $2d$, do I have to ensure that $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ has dimension $2d-1$? It seems that all of the definitions require this because we need to write the $w_i$ in terms of z and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ uniquely, right?

I am confused by your terminology.  Both your title and your question refer to a "transformation" in the sense of a locally invertible mapping; but functions like the Euclidean distance are not invertible.  How one deals with such functions varies according to the details.  Often it's easiest to compute the CDF, rather than the density, of any real-valued function of multiple variables: that comes down to computing probabilities of events bounded by level sets of the function.

@whuber I've been running into this issue for the example of Euclidean distance. It's hard to specify the $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ to overcome the lack of invertibility. I'm not familiar with your CDF suggestion. I suppose I can do this rather easily numerically, but how might I begin to do this analytically? Thank you for all of your help thus far. I've already learned so much from your comments.
