# Transformation of Uniform(0,1) random variable

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution

Let $X \sim U[0,1]$. Find the pdf of $Y=4\sqrt{X}(1-\sqrt{X})$.

I have been studying transformation of random variables and came across this exercise.

Can anyone provide me a hint on how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: [Draw the graph of $(X,Y).$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/138922/919)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to compute the CDF and hen differentiate with respect to $y$.

Here's a start, try to complete it.

Let $y \in (0,1)$,

\begin{align}Pr(Y \le y)&= Pr(-4X+4\sqrt{X}-y \le 0)\\
&=Pr\left(\sqrt{X} \le \frac{1-\sqrt{1-y}}{2}\right) + Pr\left(\sqrt{X} \ge \frac{1+\sqrt{1-y}}{2}\right)\\
&=\left( \frac{1-\sqrt{1-y}}{2}\right)^2 +1- \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{1-y}}{2}\right)^2
\end{align}