# Question regarding splitting up CDF function for absolute value or square root, example using uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

Hi lets say your CDF is from $Unif(-1,1)$
so $F(x) = (x+1)/2$

Its easy to understand how $$P(X<x) = F(x) \implies xP(X>x) = 1 - F(x)$$.

But how do I breakdown $P(|X| < x)$ or $P(X^2 < x)$? What about $P(|X| > x)$ or $P(X^2 > x)$?

Comment: Hint: For $x > 0$, $P(|X| < x) = P(-x < X < x)$. Do you know how to determine the value of $P(-x < X < x)$ from the CDF?  Also, please use MathJax to format your equations.

Comment: I strongly suggest drawing a few pictures, to satisfy yourself how an interval or set of intervals/half intervals for $X$ on the real line will correspond to some condition like $|X|<x$. Draw, draw, draw until the ideas are clear enough that you no longer need the picture to understand what's happening.

Comment: @glen_B, I think that is the best approach!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138763/pdf-of-function-of-x/138922#138922 for a worked example.